# Webpack vue loader, test production with different env

Tags: webpack, vue.js, vue-loader

I noticed that you recommend setting the `process.env.NODE_ENV` to `production`:

> Use Webpack’s DefinePlugin to indicate a production environment, so that warning blocks can be automatically dropped by UglifyJS during minification.

Is there any way to test the production version of vuejs without changing the env in `production` because I have a `preproduction` env that I would like to test before I push to the real production and the resulted JS files need to be the same as the production env, except that the name is different and on my `preproduction` and I have some different file paths.